# Get category slug of the Parent category of a Product

Tags: posts, categories, woocommerce-offtopic, e-commerce

I want to add a back button to the Single Product page so that the page will be redirected to the relevant parent category page of the product upon clicking. I have managed to get this done for one category using the following code. Here it will redirect the page to the shirts category upon clicking the back to designs button.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'content_before_addtocart_button' );

function content_before_addtocart_button() {
    global $post;

    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        if( $term->slug === 'shirts')
            echo '<div class="content-section"><a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'product_cat' ) ) . '">' . 'Back to Other Designs'. '</a></div>';
    }
}
```

I want to modify this so that it will get the current category page link of the product automatically without adding them manually like this and redirect the page accordingly. Any help on this is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have one category attached to each product, or a single product can have more than one category and you want to use one of them only? Also, should the back button text "_Back to Other Designs_" change according to the product category or it will be the same for any category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Put this below code in **functions.php** and Try it.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'content_before_addtocart_button' );
function content_before_addtocart_button() {
    global $post;
    $categories = array();
    $taxonomies = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'parent'   => 0
    ));
    if ( !empty($taxonomies) ) :
        foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
            $categories[] = $taxonomy->slug; 
        }
    endif;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    if($terms[0]->parent != 0){
        $parent_category = get_term( $terms[0]->parent, 'product_cat' );
        $parent_category_slug = $parent_category->slug;
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            if(in_array( $parent_category_slug ,$categories )){
                echo '<div class="content-section"><a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'product_cat' ) ) . '">' . 'Back to Other Designs'. '</a></div>';
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo '<div class="content-section"><a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $terms[0]->term_id, 'product_cat' ) ) . '">' . 'Back to Other Designs'. '</a></div>';
    }
}
```